# Stack build error: while building package aeson. (cabal) ExitFailure 1

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal, haskell-stack, aeson

When I run "stack build" I get an error:

```
--  While building package aeson-1.1.2.0 using:
      /Users/kaspazza/.stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64-osx/Cabal-simple_mPHDZzAJ_1.24.2.0_ghc-8.0.2 --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-1.24.2.0 build --ghc-options ""
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
```

My stack.yaml:

```
resolver: lts-9.10

packages:
- '.'

extra-deps: []

flags: {}

extra-package-dbs: []
```

command: stack exec -- which ghc 
gives:

```
/Users/kaspazza/.stack/programs/x86_64-osx/ghc-8.0.2/bin/ghc
```

command: ghc --version

```
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 8.8.3
```

command: stack build

```
aeson   > configure
aeson   > Configuring aeson-1.1.2.0...
aeson   > build    
aeson   > Building aeson-1.1.2.0...
aeson   > Preprocessing library aeson-1.1.2.0...
aeson   > [ 1 of 21] Compiling Data.Aeson.Types.Internal ( Data/Aeson/Types/Internal.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-1.24.2.0/build/Data/Aeson/Types/Internal.o )
aeson   > [ 2 of 21] Compiling Data.Aeson.Types.Generic ( Data/Aeson/Types/Generic.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-1.24.2.0/build/Data/Aeson/Types/Generic.o )
aeson   > [ 3 of 21] Compiling Data.Aeson.Parser.UnescapeFFI ( ffi/Data/Aeson/Parser/UnescapeFFI.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-1.24.2.0/build/Data/Aeson/Parser/UnescapeFFI.o )
aeson   > [ 4 of 21] Compiling Data.Aeson.Parser.Unescape ( Data/Aeson/Parser/Unescape.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-1.24.2.0/build/Data/Aeson/Parser/Unescape.o )
aeson   > [ 5 of 21] Compiling Data.Aeson.Parser.Internal ( Data/Aeson/Parser/Internal.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-1.24.2.0/build/Data/Aeson/Parser/Internal.o )
aeson   > <command line>: can't load .so/.DLL for: /Users/kaspazza/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/8b5cff025076e7bab89d6dbb5e562716cf2b67bbcde1528460c4f36feefa23fb/8.0.2/lib/x86_64-osx-ghc-8.0.2/libHStime-locale-compat-0.1.1.3-KZ1jqNx8uhlHjmuPPj6V1Y-ghc8.0.2.dylib (dlopen(/Users/kaspazza/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/8b5cff025076e7bab89d6dbb5e562716cf2b67bbcde1528460c4f36feefa23fb/8.0.2/lib/x86_64-osx-ghc-8.0.2/libHStime-locale-compat-0.1.1.3-KZ1jqNx8uhlHjmuPPj6V1Y-ghc8.0.2.dylib, 5): REBASE_OPCODE_SET_SEGMENT_AND_OFFSET_ULEB has segment 2 which is not a writable segment (__LINKEDIT) in /Users/kaspazza/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/8b5cff025076e7bab89d6dbb5e562716cf2b67bbcde1528460c4f36feefa23fb/8.0.2/lib/x86_64-osx-ghc-8.0.2/libHStime-locale-compat-0.1.1.3-KZ1jqNx8uhlHjmuPPj6V1Y-ghc8.0.2.dylib)

--  While building package aeson-1.1.2.0 using:
      /Users/kaspazza/.stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64-osx/Cabal-simple_mPHDZzAJ_1.24.2.0_ghc-8.0.2 --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-1.24.2.0 build --ghc-options ""
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
Progress 1/2
```

command: cabal install

```
cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
[__0] trying: duckling-0.1.6.1 (user goal)
[__1] next goal: snap-server (dependency of duckling)
[__1] rejecting: snap-server-1.1.1.1 (conflict: duckling =>
snap-server>=1.0.1.1 && <1.1)
[__1] skipping: snap-server-1.1.1.0, snap-server-1.1.0.0 (has the same
characteristics that caused the previous version to fail: excluded by
constraint '>=1.0.1.1 && <1.1' from 'duckling')
[__1] trying: snap-server-1.0.3.3
[__2] next goal: base (dependency of duckling)
[__2] rejecting: base-4.13.0.0/installed-4.13.0.0 (conflict: snap-server =>
base>=4 && <4.11)
[__2] skipping: base-4.14.0.0, base-4.13.0.0, base-4.12.0.0, base-4.11.1.0,
base-4.11.0.0 (has the same characteristics that caused the previous version
to fail: excluded by constraint '>=4 && <4.11' from 'snap-server')
[__2] rejecting: base-4.10.1.0, base-4.10.0.0, base-4.9.1.0, base-4.9.0.0,
base-4.8.2.0, base-4.8.1.0, base-4.8.0.0, base-4.7.0.2, base-4.7.0.1,
base-4.7.0.0, base-4.6.0.1, base-4.6.0.0, base-4.5.1.0, base-4.5.0.0,
base-4.4.1.0, base-4.4.0.0, base-4.3.1.0, base-4.3.0.0, base-4.2.0.2,
base-4.2.0.1, base-4.2.0.0, base-4.1.0.0, base-4.0.0.0, base-3.0.3.2,
base-3.0.3.1 (constraint from non-upgradeable package requires installed
instance)
[__2] fail (backjumping, conflict set: base, duckling, snap-server)
After searching the rest of the dependency tree exhaustively, these were the
goals I've had most trouble fulfilling: snap-server, duckling, base
```

(I'm on a mac, and I think the problem is with versions/dependencies of tools on my machine)
Any ideas why I get the error, or how can I debug it?

Comment: are you executing stack from within a project?

Comment: @Kaspazza Could you show us the complete output you get from `stack build`? With what you’ve given it’s hard to know what the error is.

Comment: @bradrn added. I was also wondering why --ghc-options is empty string

Comment: @bradrn I also added output of "cabal install", I think it may be a problem

Comment: @bradrn I tried removing stack snapshots (https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/740#issuecomment-177353701) 
but it didn't help :( I'm getting the same error

Comment: @Kaspazza This is a pretty strange error; I don’t believe I’ve seen it before. So I’m not sure that I would be able to help you with this — sorry! (But hopefully there’s someone else here who can help you better.)

Comment: btw, `cabal` is failing because is triying to use `base-4.13` which is the base package of `ghc-8.8.3` whereas facebook's `duckling` is build on top of `ghc-8.0.2`, so cabal is kind of conflicting the compiler version. `stack` is failing in an `aeson` dependency not in `base`

Comment: Apparently someone had the very same problem as you: https://github.com/facebook/duckling/issues/446

delete `stack.yaml` and run `stack build` worked for them

Comment: @Ismor I tried that before asking question here, but it didn't work for me, I get the same error.

Comment: @Ismor but I will try to downgrade cabal so it is using ghc-8.0.2

Comment: @Ismor I dwongraded (I think I did it correctly) but it gives the same error over and over

Comment: @Kaspazza Have you installed `ghc-8.0.2`? Just downgradding cabal won't work if it is using your a higher version of ghc. However, I'd recommend against the use of `cabal`, unless you are an experienced haskell programmer. The `Duckling` repo advise for using `stack` too. for macOS it is requiere some stuffs: check https://github.com/facebook/duckling#requirements. Once you've completed the requirements, `cd duckling` then `stack clean`, then `rm ./stack.yaml` from repo, then `stack build`. Probably will fail again, but just to be sure

Comment: Yeap I tried downgrading both, I also tried what you are writing and it is was not working. I installed haskell package (with caball and stack) on windows 10 and it is working there. So I think the best option is just to reinstall mac, or try to remove all haskell libraries/tools and install them fresh.

Comment: I reinstalled macOS, aaand I have the same error. I really don't know why this is happening.

Comment: Apparently this has been build also with `ghc-8.6.3`. Such a version of `ghc` is available in stack's snapshot `13.11`. I've check out the dependencies manually and it seems to be ok. If you will, change `stack.yaml` to set the resolver to `lts-13.11`. It'll download a different version of the compiler and libraries. Maybe it works

Comment: @Ismor YEESS!! FINALLYY!! Thank you very much! changing resolver to lts-13.11 and adding allow-newer: true (but it is because set dependencies) in my stack.yaml made it work!

Comment: @Ismor You can add answer so I can mark it solved :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### copy from my comment

Apparently this has been build also with `ghc-8.6.3`. Such a version of ghc is available in stack's snapshot `13.11`. If you wish, change `stack.yaml` to set the resolver to `lts-13.11`. It'll download a different version of the compiler and libraries. Maybe it works

#### From your comment

as you've said, you have to add `allow-newer: true` so it can resolve dependencies properly

Comment: And what is interesting, reinstalling lts-9.10 from scratch or removing and making it create new snapshots inside .stack files didn't help (as it was suggested on GitHub issue). So it was the problem with this version. allow-newer: true is needed because in my .cabal file there are restrictions about versions, and some libraries in lts-13.11 were newer than the max version in .cabal file.

But I still don't know why changing lts was necessary to work while reinstalling Haskell package, stack and cabal didn't work as this exact same code and versions of libraries work on other machines.

Comment: There are a few related issues around there while compiling different libraries, not only aeson. Always happening in macOS. https://github.com/brynedwards/spock-tutorials/issues/1. Apparently it is due to some incompatibilities between compiler libraries and system libraries related to date/time, so It wouldn't be cabal neither stack, it is the actual compiler version what is failing... hard to now, but changing the compiler version seems to help. Have you consider open an issue in duckling repo? would be helpfull for many ;)